# Character array and its memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am bit confused after reading a text book. Consider a character array `ar[10]` in C++. In the text book it says that **10 bytes** will be allocated for the array.

Starting from subscript `ar[0]`, how many elements can I store in the given array? Is it 10? If yes can I store data at `ar[10]`? I want to know how many bytes will be allocated for the array in total since I came to know that every string ends with `\0`. Will overflow happen if I try to store a character into `ar[10]`?

Comment: Char arrays are just array of 1 byte integers. You can use them to store Ascii encoded strings. But the `'\0'` at the end is still counted in the size of the array (meaning you only have space for `size-1` characters). You or whatever code your using needs to actually place the `'\0'` in it's proper place. Of course, you can also use a char array for a variety of other uses and not just as a string (ie `'\0'` isn't needed). See Sams answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If yes can I store data at ar[10]

No.

In your example, `ar` is an array with ten values. The first value is index #0, so you have `ar[0]` through `ar[9]`, inclusively. That's the ten values in this array. Count them. Most of us conveniently have exactly ten fingers. Start counting on your fingers, starting with `ar[0]`, and stop when you've used all your ten fingers. You'll stop on `ar[9]`.

Attempting to access `ar[10]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: So what about \0 at the end of every string

Comment: You have to account for the `\0` too. It's a value just like any other value in the array. If you are using it to store a string, you can store a string that contains up to 9 characters, and the \0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: You don't have to account for the `\0` if you don't need to work with the array as with a string. You can store anything in `ar[9]` but string-related functions will not work with this array. Check [this code snippet](http://ideone.com/vY5WRW) on ideone.

Answer (score 1):

It will store 10 items in total, including the '\0'. So, 9 characters, and one '\0' null terminator at ar[9].

Answer (score 0):

You can store ten values, from index 0 to index 9. This seems really wrong at first, but remember that 0 is technically a value and must be counted as one. It's sort of like how `unsigned int`s  will hold 2^32 values, but the highest usable number is actually (2^32)-1.

Note that if you want to have the array be null-terminated you will only be able to store 9 characters, as ar[9] will hold `'\0'`. You could store another character there instead, but will have to write your code around the fact that your C-string is not null-terminated.

That all said, it's generally considered bad practice to use character arrays for strings in C++. It's a lot more error-prone than just using the string standard library.

More info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 0):

Hence, you have declared a[10] so it carries 10 values. As it is char array which contains string and string is terminated by '\0'. '\0' is also a value.

So if you string length is n then your array size will be n+1 to keep n length string. Otherwise, the overflow will occur.

Observe the following example

```
int main(){

char a[1], r, t;

printf("Size %d Byte\n", sizeof(a));

a[0] ='a';
a[1] ='b';
a[2] ='c';

printf("%c\n",r); //c
printf("%c\n",t); //b
```

}

As your array size is 1. Though you have not assigned value of r,t it is auto assigned by a[2] and a[1] respectively.